# blockingqueue and Spring - how do I start thread pool at startup?

Tags: spring, multithreading, blockingqueue

I have a spring application that use blockingqueue to run producer-consumer design.  Basically when user makes an API call using REST controller, it adds a work to blockingqueue and background thread will consume the queue as soon as it's arrived.

I see that Spring recommends to use it's TaskExecutor, so I have the following class.
ThreadConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
public class ThreadConfig {

  @Bean
  public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("default_task_executor_thread");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
  }

}
```

I also have a consumer component of which watches the queue and run the task.
MessageConsumer.java

```java
@Component
public class MessageConsumer implements Runnable{


  private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;

  MessageConsumer(BlockingQueue<String> queue){
    this.queue = queue;
  }

  public void run(){
    try {
      while (true) {
        String str = queue.take();
        // Do something
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
  }

}
```

And now, I am not sure how to start threadpool when spring application starts.

Do I simply add the code in Main?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are overthinking it. Internally `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` also uses `BlockingQueue` to hand work to worker `Threads` from the ThreadPool. Since you have not changed default `queueCapacity` it will be `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

In your scenario it would be easier to make it this way :

- since every HTTP request is handled by separate `Thread`, the producer will be the `Thread` that handles HTTP request
- the consumer will be the worker `Thread` from the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

So to make the producer-consumer work, using just `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` just create a task and submit it to your ThreadPool and one of the workers will consume it :

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    private final TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(final TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test/{value}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> get(final @PathVariable("value") String value) {
        taskExecutor.execute(() -> {

            System.out.println(value);
            // do something with your String
            // this will be executed by some worker Thread
        });

        return ResponseEntity.ok(value);
    }
}
```

And also since you are using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and it implements `DisposableBean` interface (through extending `ExecutorConfigurationSupport`) - you do not have to `shutdown` the pool explicitly. Spring will do this for you when Spring Context will be destroyed and `destroy` method of this interface will be invoked on the pool Bean.